# Why do I get a stack overflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Here is the code .. I have to sort an already sorted array and to calculate it's execution time ...for quicksort it is n^2 cause it is the worst case. but for large input data let's say 7500 it gives me an overflow error :S what can i do in order to calculate the running time?

```
public class Provo {

    public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static int HoarePartition(int m, int d, int[] a) {
        int pivot = a[m];
        int i = m + 1;
        int j = d;

        while (i < j) {
            while (a[i] < pivot) {
                i = i + 1;
            }

            while (a[j] > pivot) {
                j = j - 1;
            }

            if (i < j)
                swap(a, i, j);
        }
        swap(a, m, j);

        return j;
    }

    public static void quicksort(int m, int d, int[] a) {
        if (m < d) {
            int s = HoarePartition(m, d, a);
            quicksort(m, s - 1, a);
            quicksort(s + 1, d, a);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the main class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ascending {


public static void main(String[] args){
    String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Shkruani nr e te dhenave");
    int size=new Integer(input).intValue();

    int[] r= new int[size];
    int[] p = new int[size];
    int majtas=0;
    int djathtas=size;

    for(int i=majtas;i<djathtas;i++)
    {r[i]=i;}
    for(int i=majtas;i<djathtas;i++)
    {p[i]=r[i];}

    long average;
    int n=100;
    long result=0;
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++) 
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Provo.quicksort(majtas,djathtas-1,p);
     long endTime = System.nanoTime();
     result = result+(endTime-startTime);
   long a = endTime-startTime;
        System.out.println(j+": " +a);
        for(int i=majtas;i<djathtas;i++)
        {p[i]=r[i];}
    }
    average=result/n;
    System.out.println("Koha e ekzekutimit te insertion sort eshte " + average + " nanosekonda ");
}
```

}

Comment: Use a non-recursive quick sort. Recursion will fail at some point

Comment: how can i do that ? :S I've been working on it all day and i can't do it..the deadline is tomorrow :(

Comment: Learn to debug your code.

Comment: yeah but too much to do and not time at all :(

Comment: @NeerajKrishna Even Java 6 implementation uses recursive quicksort. The point at which it fails is when the array is larger than the theoretical Java limit on array size.

Comment: BTW OP, why don't you compare notes with the JDK? Here is the link: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort1%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: i give it the size 7500,

Comment: what can i do to make it work for large nr of input

Comment: Sorry if I don't give a help for your answer but following Java naming conventions classes begin with an upper case letter and methods with a lower case one.

Comment: it is not the problem right now, i know that, it's just a test class ..thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `int djathtas = size - 1;` to `int djathtas = size;` and `change quicksort(majtas, djathtas, p);` to `quicksort(majtas, djathtas - 1, p);`

Otherwise it's not allocating 10 digits, only 9.

It seems like you're just using too large of a number. Your program can be functioning correctly and generate a stack overflow error. You could try implementing another version of quicksort that does not rely on the stack or something.

Other than that, I'm not sure why you need such a large input anyway.

Comment: it didn't ?? but why does it give me a stack overflow when n=7500 or more ? :S :(

Comment: I'm running the code on netbeans right now and I copied your entire code word by word into it. I only changed the two things I mentioned in my answer and then clicked run. It's working perfectly with no stack overflow. Are you sure you changed everything correctly? Could you re-upload your code?

Scratch that, I'm getting a stackoverflow error on 15,000 inputs.

Comment: well i edited what you told me but just in the main class ... 
i re-uploaded the code there ://

Comment: So what's the problem? I'm really not sure. Are you just trying to benchmark it to see how fast the code runs at larger size values?  Also, what is the point of the r[] array? Quicksort sorts it anyway so  your for loop that comes right after `result = result + (endTime-startTime);` is redundant. The array doesn't change because it's already sorted from 0-7499.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with memory? or it is just nonsense? :S :S 

well i have to execute it to calculate running time for different large input data

Comment: I don't know if i am asking too much but i really need help so can you give me an emal address or something like that so i can consult with you what i have already done for my project cause it's deadline is tomorrow and i've been working on it for such a long period and still i'm not sure what i'm doing ://

Comment: Yes, it does have to do with memory. When you call any function, there is memory allocated on the stack to give the function enough memory to keep track of the values of local variables and some other stuff. When  the function returns, the caller (the function that initially called the function that used the stack) pops the data it needs off the top of the stack and only stores the relevant data (all of the local variables in the stack function are released because they are no longer in scope).

Comment: Well i meant about the overflow fact..perhaps my Ram memory makes the overflow happen with a smaller value than yours ? :S 
and please about the email? :S

Comment: I'll try to help you for a bit but no guarantees I will help you figure the entire thing out. Write your e-mail in your profile or comment it here and delete it later if you wish and I'll contact you.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are stuck, you can maybe look for ***iterative quicksort*** on the web to get some help.

I have found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29467/Quick-Sort-Without-Recursion). It is dedicated to C# but translating it into Java shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Recursion depth of qsort scales with the logarithm of input size. This is not OP's problem.